# Sort order in Core Data with a multi-multi relationship

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

Say I'm modeling a school, so I have 2 Entities: Student and Class. For whatever reason, I want each class roster to have a custom sort order. In a simple relationship, this would mean giving Student a sortOrder attribute and just sorting the list by this number. Issue is, a Student might be order 3 in one Class and order 6 in another. How would I store these orderings in Core Data in a way that I can easily access them and sort my lists properly?

```
 Student                  Class
 classes  <<--------->>  students
    ^                       ^
    |                       |
unordered                ordered
```

This diagram might help explain what I'm trying to do. The students "roster" I would want to be fetched in a specific order stored somewhere, which could be any ordering. Storing this ordering is what I'm not sure how to do in a way that's the most efficient. Creating a bunch of Order objects and trying to manage the links sounds like a lot of overhead, and it feels like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Student <<->> StudentClass <<->> Class

```
StudentClass
----
studentID
order
classID
```

Then you can select as necessary.

For example, you have a `student`. Fetch all StudentClass where StudentID is `student.studentID`. You then have the `order`, as well as access to the Class.

You'll likely want to add some business logic to make your life easier. Also, if you're not already using it, take a peek at MOGenerator: https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator

EDIT: I'd really like to know why this is getting voted down. Comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't the IDs change depending on if the context is saved or not? Is the studentID a relationship or an attribute to the core data ID string?

Comment: Also that MOGenerator looks pretty cool, but my project doesn't build with it. Complains about metaclasses when I try to reference the _Student class in my Student subclass.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific. The studentID and classID would be variables *you* would set (which is obviously different than primary keys under "normal" circumstances), and not rely on the underlying SQL engine to do so. However, you'll need to guarantee unique identifiers for the respective tables.

Answer (score 1):

If the ordering of students can be described by one or more `NSSortDescriptors`, you could create a fetched property on the `Class` entity that fetches the students and applies the sort descriptor. Alternatively, it may be easier (depending on your use case) to apply the sort descriptor(s) to the `NSFetchedResultsController` that you're using to deal with the class' students collection.

If you can't use an `NSSortDescriptor`, then you'll need an `index` attribute (or name of your choice) on the `Student` entity if there's only one ordering or a collection of `Order` entities describing the index in each ordering for each `Student`.  You'll be responsible for maintaing these index values. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this in Core Data. It's just a lot of work.

Comment: The problem is that it can't be described using a descriptor, because the ordering is arbitrary and user-customizable. Once I'm able to store this order, then I should be able to use a sort descriptor to sort the results.